# Is there any good way to know when CLLocationManager's startMonitoringForRegion has completed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

From CLLocationManager.h:

```
/*
 *  startMonitoringForRegion:
 *
 *  Discussion:
 *      Start monitoring the specified region.
 *
 *      If a region of the same type with the same identifier is already being monitored for this application,
 *      it will be removed from monitoring. For circular regions, the region monitoring service will prioritize
 *      regions by their size, favoring smaller regions over larger regions.
 *
 *      This is done asynchronously and may not be immediately reflected in monitoredRegions.
 */
- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_TBD,__IPHONE_5_0);
```

Is there a good way to know when this asynchronous call has completed? I'm trying to perform another action once I know region monitoring is started for a certain region, but it looks like that can take anywhere from >1s to >20s.

Comment: What do you mean the asynchronous call. It does not complete; it monitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course yes. in the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` you will find `- locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion:` . [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate) you will find the full delegate description.